# How to select and type in an input field with dynamically generated attributes with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to automate login to Cisco Webex meetings. Couldn't find anything online so decided to try out puppeteer and make my own script to do that. So the issue I am facing is I cannot select the input fields because their attributes are dynamically generated. Plus they only have class attributes. I tried selecting parent divs and narrowing down to the input but it didn't work. I also tried to list the inputs in the page with `page.evaluate()` and `querySelectorAll()` and then choosing the inputs from there with `click()`. But somehow I am returned an empty object. I have also tried adding a 6s timeout but still no success. Btw this works in chrome console. I am baffled as to why it wouldn't work in node with puppeteer it could have solved my problem (maybe). I also tried using the `mouse.click()` but no success (Actually I am new to puppeteer and I don't exactly know how this method works. Tried entering different axes but no luck, if that is actually how it should be done). Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Environment:**

- Puppeteer version:5.3.1
- Platform / OS version:Mac OS Catalina
- Node.js version:14.9.0
- Chrome version: 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- URL: https://glsuniversity.webex.com/webappng/sites/glsuniversity/meeting/download/20868835766c4fcf82b8a7fa60a27761?siteurl=glsuniversity&MTID=m84fbf6908602bde9fb8f025ee45308ac

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**
Trying to select an input field or a button that has its attributes generated dynamically

[CODE](https://hastebin.com/azoneyiyaz.js)

**What is the expected result?**
Select the input field and type in it.

**What happens instead?**
`Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property of null`

EDIT 1: Directly selecting the input gives me this
`Error: No node found for selector`

EDIT 2: `waitForSelector()` gives a `timeout 30000ms exceeded` error

EDIT 3: Edited the exact link I have to work on

EDIT 4: I tried getting the placeholder attribute but no luck

Comment: Can you try something like this selector? `'input[aria-label="Your email address"]'`

Comment: @vsemozhebuty I tried ```'input[placeholder="Your full name"]'``` and it gives me ```Error: No node found for selector``` 
I tried ```waitForSelector()``` and it gives a 
```timeout 30000ms exceeded``` error.
 Adding ```{timeout:0}``` kinda stops the process. (nothing happens).

Answer (score 1):

For me, using xpath seems to work better in cases when I need to uniquely select an element based on its parent/ancestor class too.

Puppeteer's [page.waitForXpath](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitforxpathxpath-options) comes handy in dealing with these elements.

Below, I have tried these APIs and I was able to enter some text in input box and then click the button.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const SERVER_URL = "https://globalpage-prod.webex.com/signin?surl=https%3A%2F%2Fsignin.webex.com%2Fcollabs%2Fauth%3Flanguage%3Den_US&language=en_US";

(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(SERVER_URL);

    let elem = await page.waitForXPath("//div[contains(@class, 'el-form')]//input");
    await elem.type('foo.bar@example.com');

    elem = await page.waitForXPath("//div[contains(@class, 'el-form')]//button");
    await elem.click();

    await page.close();
    console.log('Done');
})();
```

Comment: I tried ```waitForXPath()``` but it gives me a ```timeout exceeded``` error. This the link I have to logon to : https://glsuniversity.webex.com/webappng/sites/glsuniversity/meeting/download/20868835766c4fcf82b8a7fa60a27761?siteurl=glsuniversity&MTID=m84fbf6908602bde9fb8f025ee45308ac